# How to convert index of nonzero entries of a matrix to a string

Tags: matlab

Given a binary matrix **A** of size **n x k**, i would like to create an Label of size **n x 1** such that the Label(1) contains a string which has the columns numbers of A(1,:) where the entries are 1.
for example if A(1,:) = [ 0 1 0 1 ] then Label(1) = '24'
if A(2,:) = [ 0 0 1 0] then Label(2) = '3'
if A(3,:)= [ 1 1 1 1]  then Label(3) = '1234' and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Label = {};
for i = 1:size(A, 1)
    Label{i, 1} = regexprep(num2str(find(A(i, :))), ' ', '');
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
function Labels = GetNonZeroEntries(A)  
    Labels = {};  
    for i=1:size(A,1)    
        ind = find(A(i,:));    
        indSt = num2str(ind);    
        Labels{i} = '';    
        for j=1:numel(indSt)    
            Labels{i} = [Labels{i} indSt(j)];    
        end  
    end  
end
```

Then run like this:

```
GetNonZeroEntries([0 1 0; 1 1 0; 1 1 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Without a loop:

```
A=[0 1 0 1; 0 0 1 0; 1 1 1 1];
[i,j]=find(A');
nums = mat2cell(i,hist(j,1:max(j)));
printnum = @(x) sprintf('%d',x);
cellfun(printnum, nums, 'UniformOutput', 0)
```

Output:

```
ans = 

    '24'
    '3'
    '1234'
```